# Converter HTML em PNG

Tags: php, javascript, html

Como converter, **via código** javascript ou php, o html (`DOM`) da página que está sendo exibida para uma imagem?
 
Preciso que a página mostrada ao usuário seja convertida em um arquivo de imagem no formato **png** para o mesmo fazer download e que este seja iniciado automaticamente.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu usaria a biblioteca: [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) 
Você pode ler a documentação sobre o uso dela [aqui](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image#usage)

Aí vai um exemplo:

```
var node = document.getElementById('my-node');

domtoimage.toPng(node)
    .then (function (dataUrl) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = dataUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(img); //esse método exibe a imagem na própria pagina
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('erro exibido caso falhe', error);
    });
```

---

> Como faço para abrir a imagem em outra pagina?

Simples, refira uma pagina em branco como o valor de document a ser usado.

---

> Como faço para que a imagem seja transformada e seu download iniciado altomaticamente?

```
domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('my-node'), { quality: 1 })
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = 'NomeDaImagem.png';
        link.href = dataUrl;
        link.click();
    });
```

Comment: document.appendChild(img); faz com que a imagem seja exibida na mesma página? Como faço para abrir em outra? Ou fazer o download dela  automaticamente?

Comment: @lucaswmolin isso, o método appendChild irá exibir a imagem na própria pagina. Você pode abrir em outra mudando a url referente ao document e abri-la via código JS. Para fazer o download automaticamente eu sugeriria transformar a imagem em um arquivo BLOB  e utilizar uma biblioteca como o FileSaver (link -
 https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) existem alguns exemplos na documentação, é bem simples.

Comment: quer que eu incorpore suas perguntas na minhas resposta? @lucaswmolin

Comment: Sim, por favor.

Comment: @lucaswmolin editado, espero que fique satisfeito com o resultado :D

Comment: Uma dúvida simples: my-node é qual elemento? <html>,<body>...?

Comment: É o elemento body

Comment: No download, aparece "Falha - Erro na rede".

Comment: @lucaswmolin isso se dá por uma configuração no chrome, veja esse link https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj_56O7idrWAhUJQpAKHbtxDfYQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fproductforums.google.com%2Fd%2Ftopic%2Fchrome%2F7XBU6g6_Ktc&usg=AOvVaw3S05AkdtqqRd_aiCG-tLmS

Comment: @lucaswmolin quando obtiver sucesso usando o que indiquei na resposta peço que marque como correta, ajuda os outros usuários que estão com o mesmo problema a saberem que conseguiu dessa maneira.

Comment: Aparentemente funciona, porém com páginas pequenas, que geram imagens de poucos KB. Estou lidando com imagens de alguns MB, que dão erro no download.

Comment: @lucaswmolin na documentação existe uma menção de um recurso de compressão para evitar esse tipo de erro, você também pode alcançar isso com meu segundo código ao diminuir a quality de 1 para algo menor :)

Answer (score 4):

Creio não ser possível salvar um screenshot com Javascript. Mas uma alternativa interessante é você desenhar o html que quer em um elemento `canvas`, e depois usar o método `toDataURL()` para pegar os dados em base 64, e salvar em imagem

```js
document.getElementById('desenhar').onclick = function (){
  var c = document.getElementById("teste");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}

document.getElementById('salvar').onclick = function (){
  console.log(document.getElementById('teste').toDataURL());
}
```

```html
<canvas id="teste"></canvas><br>
<button id="desenhar">Desenhar</button>
<button id="salvar">Salvar</button>
```

Comment: sensacional, não tinha pensado nessa alternativa +1

Comment: @Paz :) mas eu ainda iria pela sua, caso o OP possa usar lib de terceiros

Comment: vamos torcer para que possa rs

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a função imagegrabscreen() e imagegrabwindow(), que permite que você crie "screenshots" do navegador.

Veja os comentários no manual para saber como omitir o Chrome do navegador. Com DCOM habilitado, isso também funcionaria com máquinas remotas do Windows que foram configuradas para permitir o acesso através do DCOM.

Links:

- http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagegrabscreen.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagegrabwindow.php

Comment: Bem, caso o autor da pergunta queria utilizar essa solução em php é bom se atentar ao primeiro comentário: `For this to work your Apache service must be set to 'Allow service to interact with desktop' otherwise you will just get a blank image.`

Answer (score 2):

Tem uma biblioteca `JS` para isso também:
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html